# Decimal separator Navision Xmlport

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

Is it possible to force any numerical value exported from an xmlport to a certain custom format, regardless of regional settings?  For example, 120.25 (US) will export as 120,25?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301059.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `CONVERTSTR DELCHR and FORMAT` functions and assing the result a `text` variable.

***EXAMPLE:***

```
strNumber Txt (30)
TSeparator Text Constants '


strNumber := CONVERTSTR(DELCHR(FORMAT(ROUND("Your Number", 0.01), 0,
          '<Precision,2:2><integer><decimals>'), TSeparator,'') ,'.',',');
```

`TSeparator` Text Constant is the thousand separator in your example do not need because 125 is <  1000 but you need set your thousand separator in this variable for bigger numbers.